# Adding endl fixes code

Tags: c++, endl

In a program that I'm writing, a certain block of code only works correctly if I have a `cout << endl` statement at the beginning of it. If it is not there, the program doesn't segfault, but just gives a verifiably incorrect answer 100% of the time. With the `cout << endl` statement, it works every time. I actually have no idea what is causing this, as I've tried flushing the cout buffer using `cout.flush()` but it had no effect. Additionally, it doesn't work to use `cout` without endl. I have also double checked, and all the member variables of the `Node` struct have been initialized in an initializer list for the struct. If anyone could help me with this, I would very grateful! Here is the offending piece of code:

```
`    bool Board::CheckDistinct(Node* node, int* rec) {
      cout << endl; // if I comment this line out, it doesn't work correctly
      if(node->incoming.size() > 1) {
        Node* rec_node = node->incoming[rand() % node->incoming.size()];
        *rec = rec_node->row * num_cols() + rec_node->col;
        return false;
      }
      else if(node->incoming.size() == 0) return true;
      else {
        node->visited = true;
        if(!node->incoming[0]->visited) CheckDistinct(node->incoming[0], rec);
      }
    }
```

Here is the code for the `Node` struct (if it helps):

```
   struct Node {
      int val, row, col, dist;
      bool visited, is_white_hole, is_black_hole;
      Node* outgoing[4];
      std::vector<Node*> incoming;
      Node(int val_, int row_, int col_) :
      val(val_), row(row_), col(col_), dist(-1),
      visited(false),
      is_white_hole(true), is_black_hole(true) { }
  };
```

Comment: Are you using a library?

Comment: What's your expected output, what's the actual? And where and how do you produce said output? "It gives a wrong answer" doesn't help.

Comment: Can you give the context, where the function is called?

Comment: The expected output is whether or not there is a distinct shortest path to that node, if I comment the endl out then it always finds that it is not distinct.

Comment: And no, I'm not using any libraries other than STL.

Comment: This function's called immediately after finding the target node by BFS, and the target node is what is passed to the function. The int pointer is just a reference to the node that causes a non-distinct path.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer

Comment: Here - http://ideone.com/aUgd4J - is a minimal example, that shows, that the problem is somewhere outside this code. Fork the code I gave and try to bring it to a problem

Comment: Node* outgoing[4]; not being initialized might causing memory problems. Try std::vector<Node*> outgoing;

Comment: Ok I'll try running to through valgrind and seeing if there are any allocation errors.

Comment: You have of course enabled all compiler warnings and pedantic mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally found it. The error was in the return statement:

`if(!node->incoming[0]->visited) CheckDistinct(node->incoming[0], rec);`

I didn't have an else statement that would return if that was not true, so I guess undefined behavior occurred at this point. I still have no idea why `cout << endl` fixed that problem, but I guess that's just how it is.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the problem is that you are not returning your inner result:

```
    if(!node->incoming[0]->visited) CheckDistinct(node->incoming[0], rec);
```

should be:

```
    if(!node->incoming[0]->visited) return CheckDistinct(node->incoming[0], rec);
                                    ^^^^^^
```

The `cout` call is probably simply altering the code generation in some way (for example, the compiler may decide to actually recurse rather than convert the tail recursion to a loop, or use different registers in some way, or a long list of other things.

(Should be noted that I've seen this error many times, and made it a few times myself... It's not unusual at all!)

Comment: Ah I can't believe I missed that! Unfortunately, and I'm not exactly sure how, it still depends on the cout statement after I've fixed that.

Comment: Then I would start debugging - step through the code in various scenarios, print your inputs and the result at the end.

Comment: Or, post some complete code so that someone here can try it out. It's quite possible the error is somewhere else (you may need to break out the code to a smaller test-program, as it's unlikely anyone here is going to debug a large piece of code). Also enabled `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` (or it's equivalent) and fix any warnings it throws up.

Comment: If you get to the `}` at the end of a function without returning a value, one possible consequence is that whatever junk was on the stack will be treated as the return value; which would explain why the function call `endl` affects that.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Return value is typically in R0, D0, EAX/RAX or whatever is the "primary register", rather than on the stack.